# Add 1 month to fixed date in Smarty 2.x & show days left to that date in WHMCS

Tags: php, datetime, smarty, whmcs

I'm working with `WHMCS 5.3.x` which has `Smarty 2.x` IIRC.

So for instance `{$service.regdate}` renders:

```
2015-06-01
```

What I need to do is add one month to that date:

```
2015-07-01
```

...which I can then format with:

```
|date_format:"%m/%d/%Y"
```

...to display it how I want it.

I've tried quite a few things based on Google results like:

```
{"+1 month $service.regdate"|date_format:"%m/%d/%Y"}

{strtotime("+1 month",$service.regdate)|date_format:"%m/%d/%Y"}
```

...and a few other various iterations but the output generally renders only my initial date or nothing at all.

I'd also need to generate the number of days left from $smarty.now to `$service.regdate + 1 month` so I can show my customers how many days are left.

This I haven't found nearly as much information on.

I know you can do most if not all of this in PHP and then assign it to Smarty variables, but, I haven't found an example that works and, if you've ever worked with WHMCS support before, they don't really give you much to go on other than to `"ask the forums"`, `"talk to modulesgarden"` or `"open a feature request"`

Thank you =)

Comment: This is not the aim of the view (smarty) to do date operations for performance reasons, you should do these operations in sql first.

Comment: You are 100% correct... Luckily in this case, I had to {php} the SQL query in to get access to {$service} so this is the correct answer. Thank you for pointing out my glaring oversight! Cheers =)

Answer (score 1):

Sylvain is 100% correct and using MySQL is the proper resolution:

`{php}
        $userid = $this->_tpl_vars['clientsdetails']['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("
            SELECT *,
            DATE_ADD(tblhosting.regdate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as trialexpires,
            DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(tblhosting.regdate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH),CURDATE()) as trialdaysleft
            FROM tblhosting,tblproducts
            WHERE userid = $userid
            AND tblhosting.packageid= tblproducts.id
            AND tblhosting.domainstatus='Active'"
        );

        $services = array();

        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($services, $data);
        }

        $this->_tpl_vars['services'] = $services;
        {/php}`

Thank you =)